# redirect uri error with oauth2

Tags: php, google-oauth

I am a newbie in php, but I am a long time coder.  I am trying to get the google drive api for php working with the example files provided, but I am getting a redirect error with the following information in the message:

```html
redirect_uri=http://jppp.com:8080/interface/googletest/simplefileupload.php
```

In every answer I have seen the problem is that the redirect uri in the code does not mach that on the google console, but in my case they appear identical.  Here is the line of code (from the example)  I cant use localhost because the lamp server is hosted on docker, and google won't let you use an IP address for the uri.  I ended up changing my hosts file for jppp.com to the docker container.

```html
$redirect_uri = 'http://jppp.com:8080/interface/googletest/simplefileupload.php';
```

and here is the relevant section of my google console api credentials.  I have also waited more than half an hour in case google was slow in updating and tried it in a different browser.
[picture of google api credential screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPWxN.png)

Can anyone see a difference between the code and the console?  What else can I try to get this working?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from having this URL added as an allowed redirect_uri, you need to configure the domain itself in the Google Console.

When you add it & verify ownership, then you can play with it. The section can be found here:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It will take a bit of time to move ips and domains around to let this get a 'real' url that I can verify.  Would this lack of verification actually provide a uri redirection mismatch error?  I am currently working on dyndns, docker and getting all the ports in order.

Comment: You don't need to point it to the actual production IP address, you just need to verify the ownership of the domain. A few weeks ago I experienced the same problem and adding my domain there worked. Verification of the ownership is simple - you just need to create an HTML file provided by Google in your document root and it should work. First you add it in the Search Console, then in Developers console.